# Prevent exposing URI inside webview for local files

Tags: android, html, webview, android-fileprovider

I have a full webpage inside my device internal storage, and I want my app, which has permission to manage all files and targets API30, to be able to show it. So I created a webview that loads the index.html as

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///"+htmlpath);
```

Typical path is `/storage/emulated/0/fotoshp/index.html`. Yet, When I click an image inside the HTML, say, `/storage/emulated/0/fotoshp/0701_JB/tartaruga-tigre_JB-070210-P_00663a.jpg` I get a crash with:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/fotoshp/0701_JB/tartaruga-tigre_JB-070210-P_00663a.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I know how to handle this with a `FileProvider` for intents, but I do not know how to handle this in this situation. I don't even have an URI...

The webview code is pretty simple:

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///"+dirpath);

new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(mWebView).create().show();
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, by overriding the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method the problem is gone.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient (){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Yet, I am not sure this is a good solution...